# How does one apply analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

First question: Let f(z) be an analytic function defined in a disk |z| < r. Show that the functional equation f(2z)=f(z)f '(z) satisfied on |z| < r/2 implies that f(z) is an entire function.

Second Question: Let f(z) be a power series in z satisfying the equation f(z)=z-f(z^2). Compute the convergence radius of f(z).

Would I be correct in saying that for the second question the radius of convergence is 1? By iterating f(z)=z-f(z^2), we get f(z)=z-z^2+z^4-z^8+... which converges for |z|<1.

Comment: Doesn't analytic in itself imply entire?

Comment: @Arthur A function can be analytic on a domain. That domain doesn't have to be all of $\Bbb C \ldots$ $f(z)=1/z$?

Comment: @Arthur: Usually "entire" means "analytic on $\mathbb C$" as opposed to analytic on some subset only.

Comment: f(z)f '(z) is defined in the disk |z|< r, so this defines the analytic continuation of f(z) in the disk |z| < 2r. You can then iterate this process to obtain the analytic continuation of f(z) in the entire complex plane.

Comment: really it should be that $f$ extends to an entire function

Comment: I don't think you need analytic continuation for this (at least the full theory). If $f$ is entire, then the radius of convergence of any power series representation will be infinite, so you need to use the functional equation to show that the radius of convergence about $0$ is infinity.